Meher amount delayed and it was agreed by the girl during Nikah
Meher was decided for 51,000/- inr but it was mentioned that it will be paid after some time and girl agreed to that.
It's been 4.5 year's and how much money should be paid as meher? do we have to add the inflation rate?

yes the inflation rate should be added. specially in countries with high rate of inflation.

Mahr is settled like any other debt, and so paid in equal amount (not value). The view of the majority of scholars (see this, this, and this for examples) is that as long as the currency exists, you pay the same amount, not the same value.
However, a number of scholars think that there should be some compensation if the value of the currency has decreased significantly - usually, losing more than 1/3 of its value counts as significant. This may be agreed mutually (for example, this).
